# Program to enter an integer to its Equivalent value in word and Roman numeral

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char choice;
    int integer;

    do {
        cout << "Enter integer (from 1 to 3000)\t: ";
        cin >> integer;
        cout << "Equivalent in words\t\t: ";
        if (integer <0 || integer >3000)
        {
            cout << "ERROR! Invalid integer input";
        }
    
    //Number to words in thousands.
    switch (integer/1000)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "One Thousand ";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "Two Thousand ";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "Three Thousand ";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "Four Thousand ";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "Five Thousand ";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "Six Thousand ";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "Seven Thousand ";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "Eight Thousand ";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "Nine Thousand ";
            break;
        default : " ";
            break;
    }
    
    //Number to words in Hundreds.
    switch ((integer%1000)/100)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "One Hundred ";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "Two Hundred ";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "Three Hundred ";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "Four Hundred ";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "Five Hundred ";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "Six Hundred ";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "Seven Hundred ";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "Eight Hundred ";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "Nine Hundred ";
            break;
        default : " ";
            break;
    }
    
    //Number to words in Tens.
    switch ((integer%1000)%100/10)
    {
        case 9 :
            cout << "Ninety ";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "Eighty ";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "Seventy ";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "Sixty ";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "Fifty ";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "Forty ";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "Thirty ";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "Twenty ";
            break;
        case 1 :
            if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 0 ){
                cout << "Ten";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 1 ){
                cout << "Eleven";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 2 ){
                cout << "Twelve";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 3 ){
                cout << "Thirteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 4 ){
                cout << "Fourteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 5 ){
                cout << "Fifteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 6 ){
                cout << "Sixteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 7 ){
                cout << "Seventeen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 8 ){
                cout << "Eighteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (((integer%1000)%100%10) == 9 ){
                cout << "Nineteen";
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                default : " ";
                    break;
            }
    }
    //Number to words in ones.
    switch (((integer%1000)%100)%10)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "One";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "Two";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "Three";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "Four";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "Five";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "Six";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "Seven";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "Eight";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "Nine";
            break;
        default : " ";
            break;
    }
    cout << "\nEquivalent in Roman numeral     : ";
    //Integer to equivalent Roman Numeral in Thousands.
    switch (integer/1000)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "M";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "MM";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "MMM";
            break;
        default : "Invalid input integer";
            break;
    }
    
    //Integer to equivalent Roman Numeral in Hundreds.
    switch ((integer%1000)/100)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "C";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "CC";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "CCC";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "CD";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "D";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "DC";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "DCC";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "DCCC";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "CM";
            break;
        default : "Invalid input integer";
            break;
    }
   
    //Integer to equivalent Roman Numeral in Tens.
    switch ((integer%100)/10)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "X";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "XX";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "XXX";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "XL";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "L";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "LX";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "LXX";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "LXXX";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "XC";
            break;
        default : "Invalid input integer";
            break;
    }

    //Integer to equivalent Roman Numeral in Ones.
    switch (integer%10)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "I";
            break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "II";
            break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "III";
            break;
        case 4 :
            cout << "IV";
            break;
        case 5 :
            cout << "V";
            break;
        case 6 :
            cout << "VI";
            break;
        case 7 :
            cout << "VII";
            break;
        case 8 :
            cout << "VIII";
            break;
        case 9 :
            cout << "IX";
            break;
        default : "Invalid input integer";
            break;
    }
    cout << "\nEnter another number? [Y/N]: ";
    cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
        system ("PAUSE");
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to enter an integer with special conditions like 1111 that should have an output of One Thousand One Hundred Eleven MCXI the roman numeral does not show and ends the loop.

I tried inputting the individual loops inside the special condition but it does not do anything.

I also tried to use continue but it ruins the loop by continuing to loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You have plenty of duplicate code. For example you could create a function which prints `"One"`, `"Two"`, etc., and then call it like `print_digit(integer/1000); cout << " Thousand ";` Reuse in the hundreds and ones.

Comment: I don't know yet how to use a debugger

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: Thank you I will try to create a function which prints "One", "Two", etc.

Comment: the return is to stop the code from further running

Comment: if I don't put a return it keeps on running that special condition

Comment: I'm totally a newbie at c++ and our professor does not teach much

Comment: If you are a newbie and your professor doesn't teach you much, it would benefit you tremendously to read NathanOliver's link on how to use a debugger.  You have a bug, and a debugger is a tool for solving that problem.  You might also want to read over the Stack Overflow [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger!  A most valuable tool for every software developer.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake. Unfortunately most of the commenters want to play teacher, but do not help.

In your loop, for the numbers 10-19, you are using a return statement. The return statement will return from function main and end your program.
Please simply delete all return 0 statements, then your program will work.

I do not need a debugger to see that . . .

However, the design with the many switch cases, is a little bit complicated. STore the names in an array and index the array.